# how prove that : $x^n∑_{k=n}^{\infty}\binom{\alpha}{k}x^{k-n}=O(x^n)$

Tags: calculus

we know that :

> **(Newton's Generalization of the Binomial Theorem)**
>
> Let $x,y∈\mathbb{R}$ where $0≤∣x∣<∣y∣$ and let $α∈\mathbb{R}$. Then the expansion of the binomial $(x+y)^α$ is given by the infinite series
>
> $$(x+y)^α=\binom{\alpha}{0}x^0y^α+\binom{\alpha}{1}x^1y^{\alpha -1}+\binom{\alpha}{2}x^αy^{\alpha-2}+...=∑_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{\alpha}{k}x^ky^{α−k}$$

Now let $y=1$

$$\begin{align}(x+1)^α&=\underbrace{\binom{\alpha}{0}x^0+\cdots+\binom{\alpha}{n}x^n}+\binom{\alpha}{n+1}x^{n+1}+\cdots\\
&=∑_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{\alpha}{k}x^k
\end{align}$$
that $∑_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{\alpha}{k}x^k$ is converges  for $|x|<1$
Now let :
$$(x+1)^α-\Big(\underbrace{\binom{\alpha}{0}x^0+\cdots+\binom{\alpha}{n}x^n}\Big)=x^n∑_{k=n}^{\infty}\binom{\alpha}{k}x^{k-n}$$
And we know that $x^n∑_{k=n}^{\infty}\binom{\alpha}{k}x^{k-n}$
where again the series converges for $0∣x∣<1$ .
Now  how prove that :
$$x^n∑_{k=n}^{\infty}\binom{\alpha}{k}x^{k-n}=O(x^n)$$